# Why is the word variable different inside and outside this while loop?

Tags: ruby, loops, recursion, scope

When running the following code, I get a surprising output. Why does the value of the `word` variable change before and after entering the `while` loop in the third call to the recursive function?

```
def get_perms(word)
  perms = []
  get_perm_recursive("",word, perms)
  perms
end

def get_perm_recursive(prefix, word, perms)
  puts "---------------------"
  if word.length == 0
    perms << prefix
  end

  i = 0
  puts "Word outside loop: #{word}"
  while i < word.length
    puts "Word inside loop: #{word}"
    prefix << word[i]
    new_word = word[0...i] + word[i+1..-1]
    get_perm_recursive(prefix, new_word, perms)
    i += 1
  end

end

 get_perms("ab")
```

Output:

```
---------------------
Word outside loop: ab
Word inside loop: ab
---------------------
Word outside loop: b
Word inside loop: b
---------------------
Word outside loop: 
Word inside loop: ab
---------------------
Word outside loop: a
Word inside loop: a
---------------------
Word outside loop:
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not sure what you're really trying to do here. A loop is not a scope gate, and you're changing the size of *word* (and thus the loop conditions) on each call to #get_perm_recursive. There's probably a better way to express whatever the real goal is. Updating your question with your expected result (not just the problem code) would be a big help.

Answer (score 1):

It's not.  You're misinterpreting from which iteration the outputs are being produced.

```
---------------------  # this is iteration 1
Word outside loop: ab # this is iteration 1
Word inside loop: ab # this is iteration 1
--------------------- # this is iteration 2
Word outside loop: b # this is iteration 2
Word inside loop: b # this is iteration 2
--------------------- # this is iteration 3
Word outside loop: # this is iteration 3
# Iteration 3 has NO FURTHER OUTPUT (because i is not less than word.length)
# we are returned to Iteration 2
# but... Iteration 2 ALSO has NO FURTHER OUTPUT (because i in that iteration, increased to 1, is not less than word length)
# we are returned to Iteration 1
Word inside loop: ab # this is the SECOND while loop in the first iteration, so yes, the word is "ab"
```

Here's a simple way to modify the output to see what iteration you're in... first iteration has an `iteration` argument that defaults to `1`, and is incremented for each call to the next iteration:

```
def get_perm_recursive(prefix, word, perms, iteration=1)
  puts "---------------------"
  if word.length == 0
    perms << prefix
  end

  i = 0
  puts "Word outside loop: #{word} in iteration: #{iteration}"
  while i < word.length
    puts "Word inside loop: #{word} in iteration: #{iteration}""
    prefix << word[i]
    new_word = word[0...i] + word[i+1..-1]
    get_perm_recursive(prefix, new_word, perms, iteration + 1)
    i += 1
  end

end
```

Incidentally... it seems you're expecting `get_perms` to return an array of perms (permutations?).  But you have no mechanism to return the `perms` calculated within the permutation calls.  You need to ensure each method returns `perms` AND you need to assign the returned `perms` to a variable.

Change the first method to...

```
def get_perms(word)
  perms = []
  perms = get_perm_recursive("",word, perms)
  perms
end
```

...so that the result of the get_perm_recursive is assigned to a variable, or even better, just have the get_perm_recursive as the last executed statement.

```
def get_perms(word)
  get_perm_recursive("",word, [])
end
```

You'll also need to trap the output of `get_perm_recursive` WITHIN `get_perm_recursive`, so replace,

```
get_perm_recursive(prefix, new_word, perms)
```

with

```
perms = perms + get_perm_recursive(prefix, new_word, perms)
```

And the very LAST statement of the `get_perm_recursive` method should return the `perms` array...

```
    i += 1
  end
  perms

end
```

Another thing I'd mention, the structure

```
i = 0 
while i < limiting_value
  ...
  i += 1
end
```

...is not ruby-esque.  A more typical and nicer implementation is

```
(0...limiting_value) do |i| 
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a recursive function with a loop in it. Try adding some additional logging:

```
def get_perms(word)
  perms = []
  $level = 0
  get_perm_recursive("",word, perms)
  perms
end

def get_perm_recursive(prefix, word, perms)
  $level += 1
  puts "level: #{$level}"
  puts "entering get_perm_recursive(#{prefix},#{word},#{perms}"
  if word.length == 0
    perms << prefix
  end

  i = 0
  puts "Word outside loop: #{word}"
  while i < word.length
    puts "Word inside loop: #{word}, #{i}"
    prefix << word[i]
    new_word = word[0...i] + word[i+1..-1]
    puts "Calling gets_perm_recursive recursively"
    get_perm_recursive(prefix, new_word, perms)
    i += 1
  end
  puts "done with gets perm recursive #{$level}"

  $level -= 1
end

get_perms("ab")
```

Output:

```
level: 1
entering get_perm_recursive(,ab,[]
Word outside loop: ab
Word inside loop: ab, 0
Calling gets_perm_recursive recursively
level: 2
entering get_perm_recursive(a,b,[]
Word outside loop: b
Word inside loop: b, 0
Calling gets_perm_recursive recursively
level: 3
entering get_perm_recursive(ab,,[]
Word outside loop:
done with gets perm recursive 3
done with gets perm recursive 2
Word inside loop: ab, 1
Calling gets_perm_recursive recursively
level: 2
entering get_perm_recursive(abb,a,["abb"]
Word outside loop: a
Word inside loop: a, 0
Calling gets_perm_recursive recursively
level: 3
entering get_perm_recursive(abba,,["abba"]
Word outside loop:
done with gets perm recursive 3
done with gets perm recursive 2
done with gets perm recursive 1
```